# three internal speakers only two working

Tags: speakers

I've been working with ubuntu for awhile and I just purchased a new laptop. I dreaded having windows 8.1 so I decided to install ubuntu. My laptop has three built-in speakers (two normal speakers and one used as a subwoofer) and I can't figure out what settings to adjust to get that third speaker working.